# Flutter / Dart referencing function vs inline execution with Widgets

Tags: dart, flutter, widget

I am trying to understand why the Flutter / Dart HotReload does not work if I reference the `appBar:` widget as opposed to defining the code inline. Why?

Here is the sample code:

```
class AppBarWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold( 
      appBar: appBar, 
    );
  }
}

AppBar appBar = AppBar(
  title: new Text("App Title"),
);
```

Notice `appBar: appBar` is a reference to the `AppBar(...)` widget definition.
In this case, if I change the `title:` property text, it *will not* hot reload even though both IDE (VSCode or AStudio) says it reloads. I need to rebuild to make it work.

But if I move the `AppBar(...)` widget definition into `appBar: AppBar(...)` and change the title, it Hot Reloads.

Comment: Ok, I thought to copy the AppBar appBar=AppBar(...) as a method inside the class. Hot reload works. So I will assume functions outside a class do not hot reload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because Flutter's hot-reload is "stateful". It preserves the state of all variables – including the variable you defined.

As such, while you can change the sources of a variable, it will keep its previous state.

In any cases, you shouldn't extract widgets as global variables – but instead, extract them as *StatelessWidget* and use `const` constructor.

This has the same performances benefits while being compatible with hot-reload.

```
class MyAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  const MyAppBar({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      title: const Text('App title'),
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);
}
```